# wordpress htaccess not rewriting URL

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have installed latest the Wordpress int the */var/www/html/* of my Ubuntu 16.4 and now I am confused (?) .. I thought, WP would write a *.htaccess* during the installation? In my root there is no *.htaccess* (?) .. WP is working correctly without  one anyway.

I thought ok, but I can create one on my own then ..like described here:
https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess
.. I added a line to check if it working:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^myfolder/aaa/$ /aa.html [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

But nothing happens? what is the matter here? what am I doning wrong?

Comment: Review your [allowoverride](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride) configuration

Comment: I have checked and  set **AllowOverride All** for **<Directory /var/www/>**, now the .htaccess is considered, but still my rewrite does not work. On my other server it works correctly

Comment: Have you tried changing any settings that would flush the rewrite rules? eg https://typerocket.com/flushing-permalinks-in-wordpress/ "_In the main menu find "Settings > Permalinks". Scroll down if needed and click "Save Changes"._"

Comment: is aa.html a real file?

Comment: @Webdesigner .. yes, aa.html is a real file and accessible via http

Comment: @Scuzzy .. ok, it seems that WP had no write-privileges on the .htaccess.. now when I save the settings, it writes the .htaccess.. but still the line **RewriteRule ^myfolder/aaa/$ /aa.html [L,QSA]** is not working .. oO .. it works on my other hoster so I am now really confused about what to do(?)